# do I need to restart elasticsearch 5.x when configuration file elasticsearch.yml modified

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, yaml

Note that: the elasticsearch version is 5.0 or later. 
I modified elasticsearch.yml item named "path.data", added a path to it, do I need to restart elasticsearch 5.x?
In other words, I want to know that when I modified the elasticsearch 5.x 's configuration file, how to reload elasticsearch.yml? does elasticsearch 5.x version have this functionality?

Comment: You need to restart ES, indeed

Comment: @Val thanks, but it will lead to ES interrupt servicing, do you have any suggestions that will not interrupt servicing?

Comment: If you have several nodes, you can restart one node after another without interrupting the service. If you have a single node, you will interrupt the service. If you want 100% uptime, you need to think very carefully about your configuration before starting. Some settings can be changed without restarting, but others such as `path.data` cannot.

Comment: @Val many thanks! in addition, could you tell me that what settings can be changed without restarting?